# PDF to html and webview

Tags: android, html, pdf, webview

okay, so i am making an app (i am new to android) which will have notes of a particular subject. I'll be creating these notes in PDF format.
Now i have implemented points system in my app,
So with 100 points you can unlock the notes and read it in app and with 1000 points you can save it on your device (locally).

So now PDF viewers and all are complicated, so I'll be converting these notes from PDF to HTML and I'll put all the resources and HTML in assets folder. I will display these html notes in a WebView. So now my question is should i use an external library for WebView ? 
What i basically want is : 
- User should be able to zoom in and out (as he is comfortable reading the notes)
- Scrolling should work in webview(which usually does natively)
- User should not be able to select text in the webview (read only mode type) so that he can just not share the content.. if he wants to share, use 1000 points and download the PDF...

how do i implement this ? downloading the PDF is a later part, right now i am more concerned about

> User should not be able to select text in the webview

Is this possible ? Screenshots are okay. (i know its not but notes will be huge so screenshot will be a task too :P)

Comment: so your point is you don't want your users to copy text from your webpage right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do one thing which is you may use this following approach if it suits all of your requirements:

**1]** You can get the PDF downloaded in the end user's phone via hitting some URL (you will need an API for this) or you may place it in the app's storage:

*i)*  Assets folder - If you want to keep/store some PDF already in the app (this may increase your APK size as well as you cannot write something to the assets folder but you can read from it) or,

*ii)*  Use SQLite database - You can manage your own SQLite database for Android for storing PDFs (this is an effective approach as you can read as well as write data to this database, if implementing this), both of these storage options are fully secure unless the device is rooted i.e. data cannot be accessed from outside the app unless the device is rooted and when the user uses/grants his 1000 points wanting to save a file (PDF) on his device (locally), you can then write that file to the external storage of the respective user's device from your app's database thereby making it accessible outside of your app.

**2]** You may use the PdfRenderer class (present in Android), which enables rendering a PDF document (which was added in API level 21 i.e. Lollipop). If you use this, then only users having Lollipop and above in their Android devices can be converted as your app's end users. So, keep this thing in mind. What PdfRenderer does is, it renders every page of the given PDF into a bitmap image which can then be displayed in an ImageView, this can fulfill your requirement of the content must not be copied from the given PDF's pages as each page of the PDF is a bitmap image now that's displayed in an ImageView.

References:

*a]*  PdfRenderer theory - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer

*b]*  PdfRenderer sample (using Java code) - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic/#readme

*c]*  PdfRenderer sample (using Kotlin code) - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic/tree/master/kotlinApp/#readme

**3]** Then, you can apply ScrollView as the parent if your rendered bitmap image (single bitmap image for a single page) is large enough than the respective device's dimension.

**4]** For the zoom in and zoom out effects to be applied on that bitmap image you can use the Chrisbane's PhotoView instead of using the normal ImageView.

Reference:

*a]*  Chrisbane's PhotoView - https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

- Note: Orientation handling of the app should also be done as to give a better UX to the respective users of the to be made app. Wishing you good luck!

Comment: Okay i'll try this out today... Thank you so much for such a superb descriptive answer